# Running an gtk# Application made in MonoDev with .Net

Tags: c#, .net, monodevelop, gtk#, xamarin

Right now I am trying to learn how to use gtk# and Xamarin studio , but after I create the .EXE I cant run it with .NET. I am really new to C# and I have no idea what my program needs to work in .Net , It runs fine in mono but I would just like to see if It could work without mono .

When I try to run the Exe from cmd  I get this

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libgtk-win
32-2.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESU
LT: 0x8007007F)
   at Gtk.Application.gtk_init(Int32& argc, IntPtr& argv)
   at Gtk.Application.Init()
   at Notepad.Notepad.Main(String[] args)
```

The program I was trying to create is just a clone of notepad made in gtk# .

Comment: Are you referencing the `libgtk` lib in your current project? where did you install it..? what version of Gtk do you have ..? also try adding `"C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.8\bin"` to the path of

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the GTK# app on a different machine than the one you used to develop, then you need to have the following dependencies installed in order for your app to run perfectly:

1. The .NET Framework Runtime for the version you are targetting (either mono or ms, both are fine)
2. The GTK# Framework (You can find it here: http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/gtk-sharp-2.12.20.msi)
3. GTK+ Libraries: GTK# is a binding to GTK+ and not a full port of it. So you also need the GTK+ libraries from http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php

Notes:

In case of point 2, you can optionally include the gtk# msi as part of your installation package.
In case of 3, you can either download the full gtk+ bundle (consisting of glade and other 3rd party libraries) or just the individual runtime dlls for gtk, gdk, pango, etc for a minimalist installation.