# Unable to run GTK# app using the MS .NET runtime, only runs with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, dll, mono, gtk#

I'm programming a GTK# (GTK 2.12) application on Windows 7 (64b) using Xamarin Studio 5.3 (build 441).

I have installed the 4.0 and 4.5 .Net SDKs, and Xamarin uses .Net to "compile" my app (not Mono, which is already installed [version 3.2.3]).

When I press the "Play" button in Xamarin Studio it correctly compiles my application and starts it.

If in the command line I type "mono LightCreator.exe", then the application also runs smoothly.

But... here is where I have the problem: If I try to execute the application "directly" from the filesystem browser or typing ".\LightCreator.exe" then the application crashes.

The crash generates three log files, one of this is a binary file. Here are the text files:

First:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<WERReportMetadata>
    <OSVersionInformation>
        <WindowsNTVersion>6.1</WindowsNTVersion>
        <Build>7601 Service Pack 1</Build>
        <Product>(0x30): Windows 7 Professional</Product>
        <Edition>Professional</Edition>
        <BuildString>7601.18409.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.140303-2144</BuildString>
        <Revision>1130</Revision>
        <Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
        <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
        <LCID>3082</LCID>
    </OSVersionInformation>
    <ProblemSignatures>
        <EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
        <Parameter0>lightcreator.exe</Parameter0>
        <Parameter1>0.1.5375.20160</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>541c0170</Parameter2>
        <Parameter3>gtk-sharp</Parameter3>
        <Parameter4>2.12.0.0</Parameter4>
        <Parameter5>52cb5af9</Parameter5>
        <Parameter6>3c46</Parameter6>
        <Parameter7>16</Parameter7>
        <Parameter8>System.DllNotFoundException</Parameter8>
    </ProblemSignatures>
    <DynamicSignatures>
        <Parameter1>6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48</Parameter1>
        <Parameter2>3082</Parameter2>
        <Parameter22>0a9e</Parameter22>
        <Parameter23>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter23>
        <Parameter24>0a9e</Parameter24>
        <Parameter25>0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789</Parameter25>
    </DynamicSignatures>
    <SystemInformation>
        [...]
    </SystemInformation>
</WERReportMetadata>
```

Second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="LightCreator.exe" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="atk-sharp.dll" SIZE="186368" CHECKSUM="0xB5614E22" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="atk-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="atk-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x30ECC" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:58" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="gdk-sharp.dll" SIZE="241664" CHECKSUM="0x6DFFF0CD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="gdk-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="gdk-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x43754" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:02" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:02" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="glade-sharp.dll" SIZE="33792" CHECKSUM="0x37CBE288" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="glade-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="glade-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0xE82D" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:18" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:18" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="glib-sharp.dll" SIZE="93184" CHECKSUM="0x8E81BA23" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="glib-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="glib-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1B043" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:54" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:54" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="gtk-sharp.dll" SIZE="1399808" CHECKSUM="0xCF74A67" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="gtk-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="gtk-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x15C983" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:09" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:40:09" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="LightCreator.exe" SIZE="10752" CHECKSUM="0xD5D28E57" BIN_FILE_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" PRODUCT_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" FILE_DESCRIPTION="LightCreator" COMPANY_NAME="Ledmotive" PRODUCT_NAME="LightCreator" FILE_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="LightCreator.exe" INTERNAL_NAME="LightCreator.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Ledmotive 2014" VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="0.1.5375.20160" LINK_DATE="09/19/2014 10:12:00" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/19/2014 10:12:00" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00009e6f84923c0597ef3b370ba91ea90105ef77ffdd" PROGRAM_ID="0000da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Mono.Cairo.dll" SIZE="59904" CHECKSUM="0xCCDC21BD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION=" " FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " COMPANY_NAME=" " PRODUCT_NAME=" " FILE_VERSION="4.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Mono.Cairo.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Mono.Cairo" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="4.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="4.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="07/12/2013 07:49:31" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/12/2013 07:49:31" VER_LANGUAGE="Idioma invariable (país invariable) [0x7f]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="Mono.Posix.dll" SIZE="181248" CHECKSUM="0xF1A4B3A7" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Mono.Posix.dll" COMPANY_NAME="" PRODUCT_NAME="" FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Mono.Posix.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="Mono.Posix.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.0.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.0.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/09/2009 18:43:51" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/09/2009 18:43:51" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="pango-sharp.dll" SIZE="97280" CHECKSUM="0x23DE5420" BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" FILE_DESCRIPTION=" " FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="pango-sharp.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="pango-sharp.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT=" " VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1CA73" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="2.12.0.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="2.12.0.0" LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:55" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/07/2014 01:39:55" VER_LANGUAGE="Independiente del idioma [0x0]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="KernelBase.dll" SIZE="274944" CHECKSUM="0x81EAFB25" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Archivo DLL de cliente API BASE de Windows NT" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Sistema operativo Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="Kernelbase" INTERNAL_NAME="Kernelbase" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x49E52" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" LINK_DATE="03/04/2014 09:19:02" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/04/2014 09:19:02" EXPORT_NAME="KERNELBASE.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="Español (España, internacional) [0xc0a]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00000a832621f9dd06389f9f425e811d5e0127aedb60" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="CMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1114112" CHECKSUM="0x5B25986C" BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Archivo DLL de cliente API BASE de Windows NT" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Sistema operativo Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18015 (win7sp1_gdr.121129-1432)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos." VERDATEHI="0x0" VERDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1105AE" LINKER_VERSION="0x60001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="6.1.7601.18409" LINK_DATE="03/04/2014 09:19:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/04/2014 09:19:01" EXPORT_NAME="KERNEL32.dll" VER_LANGUAGE="Español (España, internacional) [0xc0a]" EXE_WRAPPER="0x0" FILE_ID="00004cd3e572ae6f2f7913dd8f0da01340fffe5c47b0" PROGRAM_ID="0000f519feec486de87ed73cb92d3cac802400000000" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Additional information:

because the error refers to gtk-sharp , I've copied the DLLs into the executable's directory (It's possible to tell Xamarin Studio to put a copy of the DLL files when compiles the program), but copying the DLL files doesn't solve the problem.

The copied DLLs list:

- atk-sharp.dll
- gdk-sharp.dll
- glade-sharp.dll
- glib-sharp.dll
- gtk-sharp.dll
- Mono.Cairo.dll
- Mono.Posix.dll
- pango-sharp.dll

I've also read many other similar StackOverflow threads... but I didn't find anything that helps me:

- [Running an gtk# Application made in MonoDev with .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234211/running-an-gtk-application-made-in-monodev-with-net)
- [Running GTK# Application on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921809/running-gtk-application-on-windows)
- [Can't start Gtk# Mono App without IDE (Unable to load DLL "intl")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922077/cant-start-gtk-mono-app-without-ide-unable-to-load-dll-intl)
- [Why doesn't my GTK# compiled binary (created with MonoDevelop) work on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891222/why-doesnt-my-gtk-compiled-binary-created-with-monodevelop-work-on-windows)

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to solve another problem (loading GTK themes), I've found a better solution than copying DLL files.

The trick is to add code to "find" the "missing" DLLs, in the same way the Monodevelop is doing. More info in the following link:

[How to load a GTK Sharp theme on MS Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972700/how-to-load-a-gtk-sharp-theme-on-ms-windows)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you do not have the path to GTK# configured in your PATH environment variable. Try adding the following directory to your PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin
```

The other dlls you copied are registered in the GAC so your GTK# application does not need them in its own directory.

Comment: Now I'm at home and I don't have the Windows machine to check this solution, but... why my program needs this route in the path? As far as I know, the problem is caused because my problem is unable to load the gtk-sharp.dll file, but this file is in the GAC and also in the program's directory...

Comment: The Gtk-Sharp.dll is a .NET assembly which calls out to the Gtk libraries which are Win32 dlls that exist in C:\Program Files. The Gtk-Sharp assembly PInvokes out to the Gtk Win32 dlls. These Win32 dlls need to be on your Path otherwise you will get a DllNotFoundException.

Comment: This seems reasonable :) . But I think I'll copy the needed GTK Win32 DLLs instead of modifying the PATH variable. I'll tell here the results of both approaches. This monday I'll mark this proposal as a correct solution if it works.

Comment: I've found that this route is already in the PATH variable O_O , but... copying the DLLs inside this directory into my program's directory solves the problem (except the app's look&feel is very diferent)